# Use of 'while' with Tenses?

Tags: tense, adverbial-phrases, subordinate-clauses

> 1.John helps his mother **while she cooks**.
>     2.John helps his mother **while she is cooking**.
>     3.John helps his mother **while she has been cooking**.

(A) Are the above sentences correct? I guess first and second sentences may be correct. but I don't know third sentence is correct. and,

(B)  I want to know how to use '*while*' with tenses.(For an example, when main clause is simple/continuous/perfect/perfect continuous[present,past or future], which tenses must be used with '*while* in sub-clause'?)

Comment: I've never met a girl called John, are you sure it shouldn't be _his mother_?

Comment: @JoeDark: Maybe Mary is sick so she cannot help her mother. Her friend John came over to help her mother. Isn't that nice of him?

Comment: @oerkelens then it would be _John helps Mary's mother while she cooks._ etc.

Comment: @JoeDark: There is no reason at all for that. As long as the context is clear (which it might be - but we only have one sentence here) why would you include extra words? Peter helps Mary's father in the garden. John helps her mother while she's cooking.

Comment: @oerkelens Ok, yes. If the context had previously identified the daughter, then "Mary is sick. John helps her mother ...", i.e. John helps Mary's mother, would make sense. The sentence taken by itself, though, is jarring, as it sounds like "her" refers to "John". Of course a girl could be named John, but that's pretty unlikely.

Comment: @oerkelens If any information about Mary and her parents was given in the OP then your suggestion could very well be correct. However there isn't so it's not.

Comment: @JoeDark In fairness, this is presumably one sentence pulled out of a larger context. Yes, if someone began a conversation by saying, "John helped her mother ..." that wouldn't make sense. But we don't know the surrounding context that this sentence was part of or what the writer was thinking when he wrote it, so it's possible that it did or would make sense in context.

Comment: @Joe Dark  My apology for the mistake. I edited the question.

Comment: @JoeDark: It is simply _not_ incorrect, whether more context is given or not. It is presumptuous to make assumptions about context if it is not given. The sentence, on its own, is possibly confusing, yes. But calling it _wrong_ based on your own assumed context (the mother is John's) is certainly a bridge too far.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, 1 and 2 are both valid and mean the same thing. In this context, "she cooks" and "she is cooking" are both in the present tense, so there's no practical difference.

3 does not make sense because the tense has shifted in a nonsensical way. "John helps", present tense, but "while she has been cooking", past perfect. As the helping presumably must happen at the same time as the cooking, the two ideas should be in the same tense. Either as done in examples 1 and 2, or 3 could be reworded to, "John has been helping her mother as she has been cooking."

This is not to say that it is always wrong to have two different verb tenses in the same sentence. It could make perfect sense if the events happen at different times. To take a simple example, "John IS HELPING her mother today and he WILL HELP her again tomorrow."

Comment: It seems to be "present perfect continuous", not part perfect in sentence 3.

Comment: I wonder would it be okay to say "John **is helping** his mother while she is cooking", synchronizing the tenses to present progressive.

Comment: @Jay Do you say "_John has been helping his mother while she has been cooking_" is correct (because the same tenses)?

Comment: @CopperKettle I'd say yes, no question.

Comment: @Jay So, Can I say "_john has helped his mother while she has cooked_"(because the same tenses)?

Comment: @markM Yes. As an isolated sentence it seems rather awkward, but in the right context it could make sense. But it is grammatically and logically correct.